# Create constructor for multiple functions

Tags: swift

How can I create a constructor without repeating the same code twice? I have the following:

```
static func canUserRefreshApi(lastTimeUserRefreshedApiUserDefault: String, compareTo: DateComparison, sameAs: Date?) -> Bool {
    // Function logic here...
    return whateverResult
}
```

How can I create 2 functions that accept different parameters? Because if I remove the nil variable like:

```
static func canUserRefreshApi(lastTimeUserRefreshedApiUserDefault: String, compareTo: DateComparison) -> Bool {
    // Function logic here...
    return whateverResult
}
```

I would still repeat almost the same code inside. I think I'm doing this wrong, how can I create two possibilities (constructors) for the same function? Example:

```
func multi(acceptsA: String) { }

func multi(acceptsA: String, acceptsB: String) { }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately Swift supports parameters with default values

```
static func canUserRefreshApi(lastTimeUserRefreshedApiUserDefault: String, compareTo: DateComparison, sameAs: Date? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Function logic here...
    return whateverResult
}
```

This allows to call the method with and without the third parameter

Comment: WOW!! Excellent, I was not expecting that! Thank you!